# history.goBack doesnt't work on iOS devices, how to fix that?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I made a go Back button on a page which moves user from current page to a previous one. It works fine on PC and Android devices but it doesn't on iOS. Unfortunatelly I don't have a Mac to take a look at devtools to understand what's happening. Might be someone knows how to fix that? I suspect that the reason might be in useParams and React Router, but I don't know...

GoBack.tsx

```
interface IGoBackLinkProps {
  text: string;
}

const GoBackLink: React.FC<IGoBackLinkProps> = ({ text }) => {
  const history = useHistory();

  return (
    <Link className={styles.link} to='/' onClick={() => history.goBack()}>
      {text}
    </Link>
  );
};

export default GoBackLink;
```

I use this component in this way:

```
SomeOtherCOmponent = () => {
const {id} = useParams
...

return (
<GoBackLink text={'Назад'} />
...
)
}
```

Comment: Which browser? I'm assuming Safari

Comment: Just Try `history.goBack(-1)`?

Comment: I assume that is the Link component from react-router? Is there a reason you are passing a `to` prop in addition to an onClick handler?

Comment: @ JonathanS. I tested in chrome on ipad

Comment: @joy08 if I try history.goBack(-1) then TS crashes the app ...(( I do not know how to type it correctly

Comment: `history.go(-1)` would be the native browser method for this, not `goBack()`... but like Max above I'm wondering if the conflicting "to" attribute is contributing to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<Link />` component from react-router-dom, by default, will render an `<a>` tag and it will use the path from the `to` prop as the href. So your Link is probably rendering something like this but with an onClick event handler:

```
<a href="/">
    Go Back
<a>
```

When the user clicks this link, the onClick event is dispatched and then the anchor tag takes you to '/'.

One way to fix this would be to just use a button instead of Link:

```
<button onClick={() => {history.goBack()}}>
    Go Back
</button>
```

If you must use the Link component or an a tag, `e.preventDefault()` in your onClick handler may also work.